# how to verify whether a compressed .gz is corrupted or not?

Tags: compression, zip, checksum, gunzip

I have many `gz` downloaded from the internet, and I would like to make sure they are not corrupted.

Does the fact that I can open the archive with **winzip on windows**  proves that everything is fine?

I must find a way to check their integrity without unzipping them, as they are way too big. Using Python can be an option.

Thanks!

Comment: To know if opening verifies the checksum, we'd need to know what tool you're opening with.

Comment: winzip on windows

Comment: also good ansver for similar question https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/359306/18674

Comment: Why is size a problem? Does it take too long? Take too much diskspace? Just too many files to do them all by hand?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using the gunzip test option

```
gzip -t file.tar.gz
```

See  [How to check if a Unix .tar.gz file is a valid file without uncompressing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001709/how-to-check-if-a-unix-tar-gz-file-is-a-valid-file-without-uncompressing)

Comment: thanks! is it possible to do that in python with the gzip module?

Comment: You can use           `os.system("command")` or                             `subprocess.call("command")`

Answer (score 4):

Most sites will give you a check sum of some kind to check the file is good.  Most of the time it is a md5sum but there are a few out there.  If you can open it that is a good sign but it doesn't always mean it is good.

Answer (score 2):

- Calculate the md5 hash of the file using `md5sum filename`
- Compare the 2 provided hashes (the one you generated and the one
  that is provided by the website as @Mat000111 said. if they are different, then the file
  has been modified or it is corrupted

Answer (score 2):

The gzip utility has a '-t' option which tests file integrity without bothering to unpack the file. That'll tell you if gzip thinks the file is OK.

Comment: great idea. how would I do that in the command line? sorry I am not very familiar with linux

Comment: or could I do that in python?